# Convert 3-dimentional array to 2-dimentional Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

The following is a 3-dimentional Array. I want every array like

```
array("captureTime"=>"2011-08-11 11:33:15", 
      "channel1_Data"=>"23.00", 
      "channel2_Data"=>"53.55")
```

to be stored into a **$bookArray**. I have used foreach loop. However, the output isn't correct.

Is there anyone can point out where error is? Thanks!

```
<?php
        $Books =array("0"=>array(
                                 array("captureTime"=>"2011-08-11 11:33:15", "channel1_Data"=>"23.00", "channel2_Data"=>"53.55"), 
                                 array("captureTime"=>"2011-08-12 11:33:15", "channel1_Data"=>"23.00", "channel2_Data"=>"53.55"),
                                 array("captureTime"=>"2011-08-13 11:33:15", "channel1_Data"=>"23.00", "channel2_Data"=>"53.55")
                                 ),
                      "1"=>array(
                                 array("captureTime"=>"2011-08-14 11:33:15", "channel1_Data"=>"23.00", "channel2_Data"=>"53.55")
                                 ),
                      "2"=>array(
                                 array("captureTime"=>"2011-08-15 11:33:15", "channel1_Data"=>"23.00", "channel2_Data"=>"53.55"), 
                                 array("captureTime"=>"2011-08-16 11:33:15", "channel1_Data"=>"23.00", "channel2_Data"=>"53.55")
                                 ),
                      );


        $bookArray = array();

        foreach($Books as $key=>$values){
            foreach($values as $subKey=>$subValue){
                $bookArray = $Books[$key][$subKey];

            }   
        }       
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be this instead:

```
$bookArray[] = $Books[$key][$subKey];
```

You forgot the `[]` append-to-array shorthand :)

p/s: you can replace `$Books[$key][$subKey]` with `$subValue` within the loop:

```
$bookArray[] = $subValue;
```